# Schedule to run .exe file created using pyinstaller at specific time and day.(not task scheduler)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, schedule

I have worked on a python project and have created a .exe file using pyinstaller. Now i have the executable file which i need to run on each and every machine (desktop/laptop) in my company. i am looking for a scheduling solution, where i can schedule the .exe file to run after every 2 hours and only on specific days. 
Can some one guide me to a scheduling tool or any way where i can schedule to run the executable file on every machine.

**things to consider** : A solution which don't need or say less software to be installed in all the machines. The reason i created .exe file using pyinstaller is it doesn't need python to be installed in all the machines.

Comment: You can do this using a GPO. There are many tutorials about this. But this isn't python related because it should work the same way as every other .exe

Comment: thanks.. can you share me more info about it

Comment: Google can lead you to the info you need...

Comment: @Sandap  thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the code reported above.
Note that here in the exemple I have set a sleep of **one second**, this means that every second the function checks if it is the right time to execute the job.
If your execution time precision is in minutes you can have a sleep of 60''.

```
import time

# here the time and date when you want to execute your job
datetime_of_exe = 'Mon Dec 14 12:00:00 2020'

# this is the job I want to do
def job():
    print('I am working now!')

# this function to check if it is the right datetime to execute the job
def timeToExecute(datetime):
    if time.ctime() == datetime:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# this loop works 24h and exits after the job is done
while True:
    if timeToExecute(datetime_of_exe):
        job()
        exit() 
    time.sleep(1)
```